# How can i get gridview row count

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get `gvProducts` row count.

I have tried the below code but it give insufficient result.

```
 protected void gvProducts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {

        string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString().Trim();
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        if (row.Controls.Count == 1)
        {
            //my code
        }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want the number of rows that the gridview contains or the index that the row is at or the number of controls the row contains? I'm confused by your code as to what count you are trying to get.

Comment: i want to get gvProducts row count

Comment: Then accept @Rahul Singh 's answer cause it's exactly what he gave you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want total rows in Gridview? Use `Count` property:

```
gvProducts.Rows.Count
```

**Update:**

To find the rows count of nested gridview, you can use the `RowDataBound` event of parent gridview:-

```
protected void gvProductsParent_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
        GridView gvProducts = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvProducts ");
        int count = gvProducts.Rows.Count;
   }
}
```

Please note this event will fire for each row present in your parent gridview this the `count` will change according to each row.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier - Yeah, I also went with OP's title.

Comment: I get the following error the name "gvProducts" does not exist in the current context

Comment: @ayman - What is `gvProducts`? It should be the ID of your gridview. Make sure you have `runat="server"` in you gridview markup definition.

Comment: the id is gvProducts and its nested gridview

Comment: also i have tried this code but i get Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.       GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                        Int32 rowIndex = gvRow.RowIndex;
                        GridView gvProducts = gvRow.FindControl("gvProducts") as GridView;
                        if (gvProducts.Rows.Count == 1)

Comment: @ayman - Please check my update. But please note you need to write this in `RowDataBound` event of parent gridview.

Comment: Not correct answer my master grid has more than one record and the code you suggested it counts the last child grid rows

Comment: @ayman - RowDataBound event iterate for each row, so this code will give you the inner gridview count for each row. You need to store it as somehow. I guess you are overwriting the count and thus getting only the last row count.